# Only one gameobject being affected by script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, fsm

Making a state machine AI "game" I have 3 states Movement, Combat, and View. They all work very well, now I'm making a flee (by the way if anyone has any good links to tutorials or info that they have off hand I would love that) state so I want to make all three previous state in their Idle mode. Which works perfectly when I have 1 AI. As soon as I put the rest (there is 6 total now) it will still only affect 1, but then after some time it will "release" I guess it the best term the script and just goes back to the three states that are supposed to be idle. I think that in my Coin script I am saying find and I think it needs to be something else, I'm just not sure if that's even right but based off of my previous experiences that's usually the case with Unity. I'll post some code, but here's some info that may help your eyes by not having to read through everything:

-I have a bool set up in my AIClass that is false until one of my gameobjects collides with a 'coin', and coin is jsut a gameobject i put in my game to test out my AI behaviors. When that bool is true, in my update in my AIClass(sorry it's at the very bottom of the script you can scroll down, but I had to put other code just in case I was doing something in that to cause my problem.) It sets the state of MovementState to Idle, CombatState to Idle and ViewState to Idle.

-Also, when that bool is false is the only time that the call for the transition of states occur. For example, normally the AI will search around trying to find player, if they find him they go near him, and if they are in a certain distance they fire. Pretty simple. The movement between those states happens at the end of each IENumerator when the 'NextMovementState()' or 'NextCombatState()' or 'NextViewState()' are called. So when the bool is true those should never be called, halting the AI from moving to another state other than Idle (to what it's set at when the bool is true in the update).

And this works fine when I have only 1 AI in the game.

CoinScript.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CoinScript : MonoBehaviour {

    private AIClass a;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        a = GameObject.Find ("Enemy").GetComponent<AIClass>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if (collision.collider)
        {
            if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy" || collision.gameObject.tag == "EnemyProjectile")
            {
                Physics.IgnoreCollision(rigidbody.collider,collision.collider);
                //Debug.Log ("Enemy");
            }
            if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Player")
            {
                Debug.Log ("triggered!");
                a.fleeBool = true;
                Destroy(gameObject);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

AIClass.cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class AIClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    public NavMeshAgent agent;

    //Ammo in gun before reloading is required
    public int ammo = 30;
    public int maxAmmo = 30;
    //Number of bullets a gun fires in sequence on 1 trigger pull
    public int chamber = 3;
    public int maxChamber = 3;
    //Pause between bursts or mouse presses, set to 0 for fully automatic
    public double chamberTime = 120;
    //How fast a gun fires in RPS
    public int fireRate = 7;
    public int fireTimer = 0;
    //How fast a gun can reload
    public int reloadTime = 3;
    public int reloadTimer = 0;
    //Number of bullets fired per shot
    public int bulletsFired = 1;
    public GameObject bulletClone;

    //Acceptable degrees as to which the AI will begin firing at its target
    public int firingAngle = 5;
    //Vision cone of degrees to left and right
    public int visionAngle = 35;
    public int visionDistance = 100;
    public int vRotationSpeed = 3;
    public int vIdleTimer = 0;
    public int vIdleTime = 300;
    public int searchTimer = 0;
    public int searchTime = 300;

    public int mIdleTimer = 0;
    public int mIdleTime = 300;


    public bool isFocusedOnPlayer = false;
    public bool seesPlayer = false;
    //
    public bool fleeBool;
    public bool flee;
    public enum MovementState
    {
        MSearch,
        MMoving,
        MIdle,
    }
    public enum CombatState
    {
        CFiring,
        CReloading,
        CIdle,
    }
    public enum ViewState
    {
        VSearch,
        VFocus,
        VIdle,
    }

    public enum FleeState
    {
        FSearch,
        FMoving,
        FIdle
    }
    public CombatState combatState;
    public ViewState viewState;
    public MovementState movementState;
    public FleeState fleeState;

    //Search state (knows where player is and will head to the player's location)
    IEnumerator MSearchState ()
    {   
        mIdleTimer = 0;
        int stuckTimer = 0;

        while (movementState == MovementState.MSearch)
        {
            //I've arrived at my location, if idle too long, then go back to idle state
            if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position,agent.destination) < 3)
                mIdleTimer++;
            //I'm stuck and haven't moved in a while, go back to idle state
            if(agent.velocity.magnitude < 1)
                stuckTimer++;
            if(seesPlayer || mIdleTimer > mIdleTime + 200 || stuckTimer > 300)
            {
                agent.destination = transform.position;
                movementState = MovementState.MIdle;
            }
            yield return 0;
        }
        if (!flee) {
                        NextMovementState();
                }

    }
    //Wander state
    IEnumerator MMovingState ()
    {   
        while (movementState == MovementState.MMoving)
        {
            //Wander code... Create a random angle and convert it to radians
            float randomAngle = (float)(3.14/180)*Random.Range(0,360);
            //Normalize direction vector, as we will be using it to calculate where we place the circle
            Vector3 tempV = agent.velocity;
            Vector3.Normalize (tempV);
            //Using our relative position, 5 units in front of us. Use the generated angle to find the point on the circle that we want to go to
            agent.destination =  transform.position + tempV * 3 + new Vector3(Mathf.Cos (randomAngle)*3,0,Mathf.Sin (randomAngle)*3);
            //Check to see if we are within the arena bounds, if not, push our projected vector back inside
            if(agent.destination.x > 24)
                agent.destination = agent.destination + new Vector3(-7,0,0);
            if(agent.destination.x < -24)
                agent.destination = agent.destination + new Vector3(7,0,0);
            if(agent.destination.z > 24)
                agent.destination = agent.destination + new Vector3(0,0,-7);
            if(agent.destination.z < -24)
                agent.destination = agent.destination + new Vector3(0,0,7);

            if(seesPlayer)
            {
                agent.destination = transform.position;
                movementState = MovementState.MIdle;
            }
            yield return 0;
        }
        if (!flee) {
                        NextMovementState ();
                }
    }
    //Not moving, if I don't see the player for awhile, then go wander
    IEnumerator MIdleState ()
    {   
        mIdleTimer = 0;
        while (movementState == MovementState.MIdle)
        {
            if(seesPlayer)
                mIdleTimer = 0;
            else
                mIdleTimer++;
            if(mIdleTimer > mIdleTime + Random.Range (-100,100))
                movementState = MovementState.MMoving;
            yield return 0;
        }
        if (!flee) {
                        NextMovementState ();
                }
    }
    //Visual search state, randomly look around and check to see if we see the player
    IEnumerator VSearchState ()
    {   
        Transform target = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player").transform;
        Vector3 targetPosition = target.position;
        while (viewState == ViewState.VSearch)
        {
            searchTimer--;
            //Vision Cone calculation
            Vector3 targetDir = target.position - transform.position;
            Vector3 forward = transform.forward;
            float angle = Vector3.Angle(targetDir, forward);
            //If player is within vision cone then proceed
            if (angle < visionAngle)
            {
                //Check to see if there are any object between player and myself
                RaycastHit hit;
                if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, targetDir, out hit))
                {
                    if(hit.transform == target)
                    {
                        seesPlayer = true;
                        viewState = ViewState.VFocus;
                    }
                }
            }
            //Look in another direction
            if(searchTimer < 0)
            {
                searchTimer = searchTime + Random.Range (-100,100);
                targetPosition = new Vector3(Random.Range (-100,100),transform.position.y,Random.Range (-100,100));
            }
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation,Quaternion.LookRotation(targetPosition - transform.position), vRotationSpeed*Time.deltaTime);

            yield return 0;
        }
        if (!flee) {
                        NextViewState ();
                }
    }
    //Focus on player
    IEnumerator VFocusState ()
    {   
        Transform target = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player").transform;
        while (viewState == ViewState.VFocus)
        {
            //Vision Cone calculation
            Vector3 targetDir = target.position - transform.position;
            Vector3 forward = transform.forward;
            float angle = Vector3.Angle(targetDir, forward);
            if (angle > visionAngle)
                viewState = ViewState.VIdle;
            else
            {
                RaycastHit hit;
                //Check if there are any objects in the way
                if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, targetDir, out hit))
                {
                    if(hit.transform == target)
                    {
                        //Tell other AI where player is
                        GameObject[] objArray = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Enemy");
                        AIClass[] enemyArray = new AIClass[objArray.Length];
                        for(int i = 0; i < enemyArray.Length; i++)
                        {
                            enemyArray[i] = (AIClass)objArray[i].GetComponent(typeof(AIClass));
                            if(i >= enemyArray.Length/2)
                                enemyArray[i].agent.destination = target.position;
                            else
                                enemyArray[i].agent.destination = target.position + target.forward*5;
                            enemyArray[i].movementState = MovementState.MSearch;
                        }
                        seesPlayer = true;
                        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation,Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - transform.position), vRotationSpeed*Time.deltaTime);
                        //Check to see player is within sights of the gun
                        if (angle < firingAngle)
                            isFocusedOnPlayer = true;
                        else
                            isFocusedOnPlayer = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //I no longer see the player
                        seesPlayer = false;
                        viewState = ViewState.VIdle;
                        isFocusedOnPlayer = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            yield return 0;
        }
        if (!flee) {
                        NextViewState ();
                }
    }
    //Visual idle state, basically the ai is just looking forward
    IEnumerator VIdleState ()
    {   
        vIdleTimer = 0;
        Transform target = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player").transform;
        while (viewState == ViewState.VIdle)
        {
            //Vision cone calculation
            vIdleTimer++;
            Vector3 targetDir = target.position - transform.position;
            Vector3 forward = transform.forward;
            float angle = Vector3.Angle(targetDir, forward);
            //Check to see if there is an object is between the ai and the player
            if (angle < visionAngle)
            {
                RaycastHit hit;
                if (Physics.Raycast(transform.position, targetDir, out hit))
                {
                    if(hit.transform == target)
                    {
                        seesPlayer = true;
                        viewState = ViewState.VFocus;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(vIdleTimer > vIdleTime)
                viewState = ViewState.VSearch;
            yield return 0;
        }
        if (!flee) {
                        NextViewState ();
                }
    }
    //Firing gun state
    IEnumerator CFiringState ()
    {   
        while (combatState == CombatState.CFiring)
        {
            if(!isFocusedOnPlayer)
                combatState = CombatState.CIdle;
            fireTimer--;
            if(ammo > 0)
            {
                if(chamber > 0)
                {
                    if(fireTimer <= 0)
                    {
                        for(int i = 0; i < bulletsFired;i++)
                        {
                            GameObject temp = (GameObject) Instantiate (bulletClone,transform.position + transform.forward,transform.rotation);
                            temp.rigidbody.AddForce(transform.forward*500);
                        }
                        fireTimer = 60 / fireRate;
                        ammo--;
                        chamber--;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    chamber = maxChamber;
                    fireTimer = (int)(60/chamberTime);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                combatState = CombatState.CReloading;
            }
            yield return 0;
        }
        if (!flee) {
                        NextCombatState ();
                }
    }

    IEnumerator CReloadingState ()
    {
        reloadTimer = reloadTime * 60;
        while (combatState == CombatState.CReloading)
        {
            reloadTimer--;
            if(reloadTimer <= 0)
            {
                ammo = maxAmmo;
                combatState = CombatState.CIdle;
            }
            yield return 0;
        }
        if (!flee) {
                        NextCombatState ();
                }
    }

    IEnumerator CIdleState ()
    {   
        while (combatState == CombatState.CIdle)
        {
            if(isFocusedOnPlayer)
                combatState = CombatState.CFiring;
            yield return 0;
        }
        if (!flee) {
                        NextCombatState ();
                }
    }

    void Start ()
    {
        fleeBool = false;
        flee = false;
        NextCombatState();
        NextViewState();
        NextMovementState();
    }
    void NextMovementState()
    {   
        string methodName = movementState.ToString() + "State";
        System.Reflection.MethodInfo info = GetType().GetMethod(methodName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        StartCoroutine((IEnumerator)info.Invoke(this, null));
    }
    void NextCombatState ()
    {
        string methodName = combatState.ToString() + "State";
        System.Reflection.MethodInfo info = GetType().GetMethod(methodName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        StartCoroutine((IEnumerator)info.Invoke(this, null));
    }
    void NextViewState ()
    {
        string methodName = viewState.ToString() + "State";
        System.Reflection.MethodInfo info = GetType().GetMethod(methodName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        StartCoroutine((IEnumerator)info.Invoke(this, null));
    }

    void NextFleeState()
    {
        string methodName = viewState.ToString() + "State";
        System.Reflection.MethodInfo info = GetType().GetMethod(methodName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        StartCoroutine((IEnumerator)info.Invoke(this, null));
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, transform.position+transform.forward*5, Color.red);
        if (fleeBool == true) 
        {
            flee = true;
        }

        if (flee == true) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("flee is true");
            combatState = CombatState.CIdle;
            movementState = MovementState.MIdle;
            viewState = ViewState.VIdle;
            Debug.Log ("End of idles");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I do think the problem is that I am saying GameObject.Find("Enemy") and after looking at documentation from Unity, I think that only finds one. So to narrow my question down more I really do think that is the problem and I wonder how I can do this but with every single AI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GameObject.FindObjectsOfType()](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectsOfType.html) or [GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can do that with store all the AIClass into array and then loop it become specific, so every enemy can affected

```
AIClass[] AIObject = GameObject.Find("Enemy").GetComponents<AIClass>();  
foreach(AIClass a in AIObject ){  
 //do something with a
}
```

it should work.